# Elm: How to merge two dictionaries?

Tags: dictionary, elm

I have two dictionaries, and their values incidcate type effectiveness of a Pokémon attack. Now I want to combine these to have the combined effectiveness.

So for instance, one dictionary has:

```
 normal -> 0.5
 fire -> 2
```

The other has:

```
 water-> 0.5
 fire -> 2
```

The combined would be:

```
 normal -> 0.5
 water-> 0.5
 fire -> 4
```

I found a function for dict called `merge`: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.2/Dict#merge, but can't figure out how to use it, nor could I find an example.

So, how do you use Dict.merge? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The signature might be confusing you because it isn't restricted to merging into a new `Dict`, but could merge into a list of key-value pairs instead, for example. When reading the signature in your case you can replace `result` with `Dict comparable c`. or even use `Int` in place of both `a`, `b` and `c`.

Edit: For easy reference, the signature is:

```
merge :
    (comparable -> a -> result -> result)
    -> (comparable -> a -> b -> result -> result)
    -> (comparable -> b -> result -> result)
    -> Dict comparable a
    -> Dict comparable b
    -> result
    -> result
```

When using it, in order to return an new `Dict` we have to pass it `Dict.empty` as the initial value and insert the values into the dictionary in each function ourselves, like this:

```
dictA =
    Dict.fromList [ ( "normal", 0.5 ), ( "fire", 2 ) ]


dictB =
    Dict.fromList [ ( "water", 0.5 ), ( "fire", 2 ) ]


merged =
    Dict.merge
        (\key a -> Dict.insert key a)
        (\key a b -> Dict.insert key (a + b))
        (\key b -> Dict.insert key b)
        dictA
        dictB
        Dict.empty
```

Comment: First and third arguments to `Dict.merge` can be eta-reduced to `Dict.insert`. Nice answer.